# Wireless driver installation on LG-X130 8.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, 8.04, ralink, lg

Recently installed 8.04.
I can't connect through wireless.
I have a wired connection. My card is a Ralink rt3090

Comment: Can you please give details of your wireless card?

Comment: it must be ralink rt3090

Answer (score 1):

For some people the following Kernel Module works.

https://launchpad.net/~markus-tisoft/+archive/rt3090/+files/rt3090-dkms_2.3.1.3-0ubuntu0~ppa1_all.deb

Otherwise you can have a look at this thread

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1600498